# create and update column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need this code to create one column and then make it another foreign key.

I do not want another code, I need this for certain reasons. How can I add code to modify the created column and make it a foreign key?

```
-- Actualizando la tabla: action

DELIMITER $$
SET @s = (SELECT IF(
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'action'
AND table_schema = 'ibexsales_dev'
AND column_name = 'company_id'
) > 0,
"SELECT 1",
"ALTER TABLE action ADD company_id INT(11) NOT NULL"
));
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
$$ DELIMITER ;
```

I need add this code:

```
ALTER TABLE `ibexsales_dev`.`action` 
                    ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_company_id_action` 
                    FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES company(`company_id`);
```

I tried this but it does not work:

```
) > 0,
"SELECT 1",
"ALTER TABLE action ADD company_id INT(11) NOT NULL",
"    ALTER TABLE `ibexsales_dev`.`action` 
                    ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_company_id_action` 
                    FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES company(`company_id`); "
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't repeat `ALTER TABLE`. A single `ALTER TABLE` query can contain multiple alterations, separated by comma.

```
) > 0,
"SELECT 1",
"ALTER TABLE action ADD company_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
                    ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_company_id_action` 
                        FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES company(`company_id`); "
));
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. What is the name of the structure I used? (I did not know what could be done that way, I have seen the example on the internet)

Comment: You had too many arguments to `IF()`. It's just `IF(condition, trueResult, falseResult)`, but you had `IF(condition, trueResult, falseResult, anotherFalseResult)`. The "name" is syntax error.